# RegisterMonoModules.cpp needs editing to fix error: #endif without #if #endif

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

When using Unity 5 (B18) and building for iOS the following error occurs:

```
.../RegisterMonoModules.cpp:87:2: error: #endif without #if #endif // !(TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR) && !defined(__arm64__)
```

Easy to fix - just remove the #endif on the line above the one generating the error

But then you need to add -fno-objc-arc to Build Phases to file FbUnityInterface.mm

What I find irritating is that every time the project is built the RegisterMonoModules.cpp needs to be edited again. Is there a way to get the change to "stick"?

Same problem in both Facebook-unity-sdk 6.0 and 6.1

Comment: Changing FixupFiles.cs line 39-40 to `   data = Regex.Replace(data, @"mono_aot_register_module\(mono_aot_module_mscorlib_info\);",
                        "mono_aot_register_module(mono_aot_module_mscorlib_info);");
` or just remove these lines - will fix the first problem.

Comment: to disable ARC select your app "target" under 'build phases' look for 'FbUnityInterface' double click on 'compiler flags' and past this '-fno-objc-arc' it may show errors so build your game again with append option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapting @bjornrun's comment into an answer: in unity 4.6.9 with facebook plugin 6.2.2, I had to change both the `data =` lines in the code block starting on line 40 of Facebook/Editor/iOS/FixupFiles.cs to just this:

```
data = Regex.Replace(data, @"mono_aot_register_module(mono_aot_module_mscorlib_info);", "mono_aot_register_module(mono_aot_module_mscorlib_info);");
```

After that, mono compiled fine.

I'm also using Heyzap's plugin, and I had to change their PostProcessBuild attribute in HeyzapPostBuild from 102 to 99, which puts it just before Facebook's 100.